# How enable/disable WiFi adapters individually under 10.04

Tags: 10.04, wireless

I have a laptop with an internal wifi G adapter, and I have an external USB wifi adapter that is compatible with N. the internal wifi can be disabled using a little switch on the side of the laptop. However, when I disable it using the switch, it disables **ALL** Wifi adapters, internal or external.

I want to use the external USB adapter, since it's faster.

Also, on my EeePC, I cannot seem to be able to disable the internal WiFi adapter. The blue light remains ON, which means I cannot use my EeePC in an airplane.

How can I fix those problems ?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first problem you can disable it by blocking the driver from loading. Use `lsmod` to find the driver it uses and then add `blacklist that-driver` to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` (on a new line). Bit of a sledgehammer approach but it would disable it.

I don't know if this would actually disable the hardware so it might still eat battery.

Comment: Well, it is part of the solution for me, as it will not show in my discovered sites under this unused adapter. I only have to see whether the other device will remain available if I manually turn the wireless off on my main laptop. But it is worth a try.

Comment: There might also be a BIOS option for disabling WiFi that might be more reliable than blocking its driver. But I can't say as I'd hold much hope for that because laptop BIOSes are usually a bit rubbish.