# How can I permanently disable the internal WiFi adapter?

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager

I recently installed a Linksys Wireless-N Notebook Adapter w/Dual-Band (WPC600N), which is working nicely via the PCMCIA slot; however, I cannot find where to permanently disable the internal WiFi adapter.  Currently, I'm forced to manually disable it with each reboot.

Comment: Is there a BIOS setting you can switch?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How enable/disable WiFi adapters individually under 10.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/3362/how-enable-disable-wifi-adapters-individually-under-10-04)

Answer (score 4):

Unless there is a hardware switch to turn it off, just blacklist the module.

You can find out which module is in use with this:

```
lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net
```

...to blacklist a module, add `blacklist module_name` to /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf

Comment: Thanks for the information. Being an old DOS hack, I was able to figure out what changes to make and where to make them, but I've been unable to save them to the blacklist.conf file. i don't seem to have permission to modify the file. Any comments?

Comment: You have to open it with super user privileges, like this: `gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`. If you need help with the module names, post the output of `lsmod`.

Comment: Thanks mikewhatever, I'll give that a whirl.  Hopefully, there won't be any follow-up questions.  I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line to `/etc/network/interfaces`:

`iface wlan0 inet manual`

(Replace `wlan0` with the interface you want to disable)

Comment: How does this disable the interface? I already had that line and the interface was never disabled. It even survived reboots.