# Disabled WiFi but it keeps re-enabling itself; want it to stay disabled

Tags: wireless

I have an Alienware X51 desktop with a wireless card, I have it connected via ethernet and want to permanently disable WiFi from ever using itself.

When running Windows, I go to device manager and rightclick-disable the Wireless card and that takes care of my problem. Is there a similar method using Ubuntu 14.04?

For now, I click on the network icon in the system tray and uncheck 'Enable wifi' but it seems to turn itself back on as I use my computer, I think I have the incident isolated to something with Steam. It seems like after I start the Steam client it always is re-enabled.

Hopeful answer: Just disable/remove/block wireless card from ever working.

EDIT: Ok, it is official, the game client Steam is enabling WiFi every single time I launch it, even after going to Settings>Network>Wireless>Disable & Airplane mode on.
Any idea why the client is activating WiFi when I have a perfectly good ethernet connection?

Comment: Possible duplicate. http://askubuntu.com/questions/116309/how-can-i-permanently-disable-the-internal-wifi-adapter

Comment: BTW, [the Steam bug has been reported](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/3424).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to permanently disable the wireless, blacklist its driver. Find the driver with:

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

Under the wireless device, the driver will be shown. As an example:

> *-network
>          description: Wireless interface
>          product: Centrino Advanced-N 6200
>          vendor: Intel Corporation
>          physical id: 0
>          logical name: wlan0
>          clock: 33MHz
>          capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
>          configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.13.0-etc.

In this case, we'd blacklist *iwlwifi*. From the terminal:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist iwlwifi"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
modprobe -r iwlwifi
exit
```

There are a couple of drivers that don't report exactly in *lshw*. If the driver shows as wl0, you need to blacklist wl. If it shows as b43-pci-bridge, you need to blacklist b43. If in doubt, post your result and we'll be happy to help.

You should be all set.

Answer (score 4):

Fire up the terminal and type this

```
rfkill list all
```

Note Down the number corresponding to wlan and use this command

```
rfkill block 1
```

replace 1 with the number of your wireless card

Answer (score 1):

Please run the following command and copy the results here

## ifconfig -a

This will show the interface name of you Wifi interface.

You usually will get something like (wlan0, ath0, wifi0, or eth0 )

I will explain further down assuming that your interface name is wlan0

issue the following command (in a terminal)

## sudo ifdown wlan0

Now remove the config file for the wlan0 (your wifi)

## sudo rm /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-wlan0

P.s when using sudo , you will be requested to enter your root password.

after that your wifi will be disabled till the config file re-created again (this can be done manually or through the network manager you installed)

Comment: This does not answer the question. :) . For queries like these, comment on the question.

Comment: Ok then , I do not really know the rules of this website :)

Comment: My answer was edited completely , Thanks Kasisnu

Comment: You're welcome! Nicely done! It's probably best just to backup the file. Not too sure about that though.

Comment: @AhmedElsokary  /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-wlan0 is not an Ubuntu file, I believe it is a Red Hat/Fedora/CentOS file.