# How I can prevent my WiFI enable itself?

Tags: 14.04, wireless, networking

I'm often use my LAN connection than WiFi so I keep WiFi disabled.
But in some case (looks like randomly) system enable it.
So how I can disable it till I need it?

I see this post [Disabled WiFi but it keeps re-enabling itself; want it to stay disabled](https://askubuntu.com/questions/514064/disabled-wifi-but-it-keeps-re-enabling-itself-want-it-to-stay-disabled) but answers says just how to remove connection since I need just disable it.

Comment: Try running this command in a terminal window right after login **sudo ifdown wlan0** each time you want to use your LAN connection. If you want to use wifi connection reboot your computer. Visit [this page](http://askubuntu.com/questions/3677/disable-wireless-on-startup) for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to "Edit Connections" and select your WiFi connection. Then in edit, in the general tab, uncheck the first option of - Automatically connect to this network when it is available.

[image: Disable WiFi automatic connection]

Comment: yep, this is answer
shame on me :)